# Changing MatLab default image interpolation method

Tags: image, matlab

I am creating a MatLab GUI for analyzing and interacting with large, very detailed images, and displaying the image using the imshow() function. However, the interpolation when zoomed out causes the images to be completely illegible. If I resize the image using imresize() with bicubic interpolation and then display it, the results look fine. This is a very impractical solution though, because you cannot easily dynamically zoom in and out while interacting with the image.

What I need is to change the interpolation method of the default image scaling to bicubic or similar. Is this possible, or is there another viable solution?

Comment: By default, imresize uses bicubic interpolation. If you implement your own scale, then you can apply whatever interpolation you wish. Which scale function are you using ? add code ?

Comment: [This movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3RSufKLc_Y) may explain what you are looking for.